# Using MEF and Lazy<T,TMetadata> under VS2012

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, mef, composition

I'm in the process of taking some MEF code I wrote in VS2010, and writing it again in VS2012.  Unfortunately, I got stuck on this simple interface:

```
  public interface IModulesContainer
  {
    [ImportMany]
    IEnumerable<Lazy<IModule, IModuleMetadata>> Container { get; }
  }
```

VS2012 has a compile error on this:

```
Error   Using the generic type 'System.Lazy<T>' requires 1 type arguments
```

I know there are two System.Lazy<> generic classes, one that takes one parameter type, and the other takes two (2nd being metadata).

I can't figure out how to get VS2012 to recognize the latter class.  (Both are under the System namespace)

VS2010 sees it just fine.  What am I missing?

Thanks in advance,
--Eric

Comment: Have you added a reference to the `System.ComponentModel.Composition` assembly?

Comment: Holy Cow!  That was it!

Comment: So the Lazy<T,TMetadata> is inside System.Component.Composition.dll, even though it's under the System namespace.  I hate it when Microsoft does this, if it's under the System namespace, it should be w/in the System.dll.  Also, I installed MEF through NuGet, so I made the assumption that all was pulled correctly.  Apparently, you still need to reference the S.C.C dll, in addition.  Thanks for your suggestion